# C++ Array Iteration

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

Can anyone spot the reason why nothing gets printed onto console using below C++ code;

```
string array[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

int length = sizeof(array);
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] != "") cout << array[i];
    }
}
catch (exception &e)
{
    e.what();
}
```

Comment: As an aside, `sizeof(array)` returns the number of bytes in the array, not the number of elements in it; and so this won't do what you think it does...

Comment: What is that `string` in your case?

Comment: On another note, what is the try... catch... for? There are no operations in that loop that could throw, apart from the UB (unless someone has been messing with the ios::exceptions flags for cout).

Comment: Also, the `e.what()` expression could be reasonably expected to have no side-effects (it does not have side effects for any standard exceptions), so what is it doing there as a complete statement on its own?

Comment: try/catch removed. thank you all for directing the code towards the right cause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the wrong length:

```
int length = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])
```

The actual reason you don't see anything on the console is because the output is buffered, and since you haven't wrote a newline it's not flushed. In the meantime your app crashes.

Comment: The question was why nothing printed, not why his for loop didn't loop properly. Further sizeof(std::string) should be 16 (VC, other compliers will have diffent values), which is enough to loop it the length of the array, and should through the exception in the end because of out of bounds

Comment: @Steven going out of bounds in C++ is undefined behaviour. It should not be expected to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

No end of line character.

Also as mentioned by Dave, sizeof is not the length of the array

Comment: What does end of line have to do with anything?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: He was talking about endl. endl flushes the buffer as well as print a new line character.

Comment: @Steven an end of line character does not cause output to be emitted. That happens when you flush the buffer. `cout << endl;` (for example) does both, which may be the source of your confusion; but `cout << "foo\n"` will not necessarily show anything. You can also do e.g. `cout << "foo" << flush;` to show the output without a newline.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that `string` == `std::string`.

let T be an arbitrary type, and n be an arbitrary positive integer - then:

```
sizeof(T[n]) == n * sizeof(T)
```

That is - `sizeof(array)` is not the length of the array, but the total amount of memory used by the array (in `char`s). Your `std::string` implementation could very well be using more than 1 `char`'s worth of memory to store its structure. This leads to `length` holding a value much greater than 4.

This causes the program to read from past the end of `array`; an operation for which C++ imposes no requirements (it is Undefined Behaviour).

In terms of the C++ abstract machine, a program containing Undefined Behaviour can do absolutely anything, **even before the point in the execution of the program at which the Undefined Behaviour was encountered**. In your particular case your program exhibits this behaviour by not printing anything (even though you had made 4 well defined calls to `operator<<` before the erroneous array indexing).

You have tagged this `eclipse-cdt`, so I will assume that you are using GCC to compile your program, and are running it under a modern operating system with memory-protection. In this case the actual reason for the behaviour that you are seeing is probably that `std::cout` is buffering the first few strings that you stream into it and so not immediately printing them to the console. After that you get to the buffer overrun and your operating system interrupts the process with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` signal or similar. This causes the immediate termination of your program, which does not give std::cout a chance to flush its buffered values. All up, this means that nothing gets printed.

As mentioned in another answer, you should replace the line:

```
length = sizeof(array);
```

with:

```
length = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

This will guarantee that `length` will hold the value `4`, rather than the value `4 * sizeof(string)`, that could be many times the length of the array.